# How to sleep execution in while cycle in Monotouch Button TouchDown event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling, xamarin.ios, uibutton

I tried `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in every iteration in cycle, but `infoLabel.Text` is not changed until end of cycle.It changes infoLabel.Text after calling Thread.Sleep 3 times.
Please advice. Here's my code.

```
void Handle_Touchdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
 {
    infoLabel.Text = i.ToStraing();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably better off implementing a `NSTimer` and incrementing a count. Possible code could look like:

```
void Handle_Touchdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NSTimer timer;
    int counter = 0;

    timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(1, delegate{
        if (counter != 10)
        {
            counter++;
            infoLabel.Text = i.ToString();
        }
        else
            timer.Invalidate() // stop the timer
    });
}
```